# Django: How to run python scripts on a running env with gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I was wondering how I could run some external python scripts on my django application while it is running with gunicorn and nginx ?

Locally without gunicorn and web server, I would just open a python shell using the below:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then run my python script on my django application with the following:

```
exec(open('myscript.py').read())
```

Can you please advise ?

PS: I need to run the script on specific time and not on the startup.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can just import the script into one of your Django project files like `settings.py` and then it will just run at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @rob-kwasowski for your reply, actually I need to run the scripts at specific times and not at the startup.

Comment: @MarVin What times?

Comment: Normally once a week. I would want to manually do it and avoid integrating schedulers with celery etc.. since I am not tightly constrained by the moment of execution of these scripts.